# Is there any way to bypass or script Heroku's login prompt?

Tags: heroku, docker, continuous-integration

The Heroku Toolbelt's login prompt has started causing my continuous integration job to fail. I'm guessing something changed in a recent version, but since this project had been on the back-burner for a few months, I'm not sure exactly when that happened. I'll also admit that I don't remember how I had this working in the first place. It's possible that I did something similar to my answer below, but have no recollection of that.

Is there any way to script completion of the login prompt or bypass it entirely using environment variables/config?

Version information:

- heroku-toolbelt/3.42.40 (x86_64-linux) ruby/2.2.2
- heroku-cli/4.27.26-693efcb (amd64-linux) go1.6

I've tried manually logging into Heroku on the CI server, which creates a .netrc and copying that into my image, but it appears to be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the only solution I was able to come up with was to build the Docker image, create a container, run `heroku login` inside of it, commit the changes and use the new image in my CI workflow.